# How to share code versioned Ruby Modules between developers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module

I work with a team of developers that is transitioning to Ruby on Rails for some web development projects. We expect that in the development process we will develop shared code. I understand that Gems are one method to share code, but in some cases a Module may be a better approach for us from a development standpoint.

My question is if Programmer A develops a module that Programmer B would like to use in his/her project, what is the best way(s) to do it when the module is in a Git repository? For example, Programmer A might maintain the module, and Programmer B may want to take advantage of new features in the module, so Programmer B simply copying the module file into his/her application isn't an option.

Assume that a `SharedModules` repository exists which holds various modules (e.g., `module1.rb`, `module2.rb`, etc) in a Modules folder. Programmer B can clone the `SharedModules` repository, but may be interested in just using one module (`module1.rb`) in his/her application. How can Programmer B accomplish this and still ensure that pulling the `SharedModules` repository will update `module1.rb` in his/her application? Is there some kind of symlink-based approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could setup a repo for each module and then use git **Submodules**: http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules

> Submodules allow you to
>   keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository.
>   This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your
>   commits separate.